# Export to Database or CSV Expired

Tags: powershell

I need a help to export the script below direct to database or to csv . I dont wanna much about script and I need help pls. I need to know which users inside a group will expire the password and date , the script works good but I cannot found a way to export.

The script is

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember "GROUPNAME"
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $user.name } -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 
    Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed") } }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for it before you came here for asking? There are several examples right here in SO of how to do it. Either you save the output of your foreach loop to a variable and pipe this variable to `Export-CSV` afterwards or you use the output of your `Get-ADGroupMember "GROUPNAME"` pipe it to a `Foreach-Object` loop and pipe this to `Export-CSV`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$b=@()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $a=Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $user.name } -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed") } }

    $b += $a
    }
$b |Export-Csv C:\Temp\export.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help friend... keep safe